# Как записать в файл следующие значения массива по встречающейся строке?

Tags: powershell

Есть файл с данными, если встречается $string, то как записать значение которые идут следующими после $string до встречающейся строки $string2, и следующии значения от $string2 до $string3.

- Строка1 ($string)
- данные
- данные
- Строка2 ($string2)
- данные
- данные
- Строка3 ($string3)
- данные
- данные

Comment: Записать куда? Если честно, не ясно что же требуется в конечном итоге: просто отбросить все строки с `$string*`? Если так, достаточно ```Select-String "$string\d" -no X:\input\file.txt | ForEach-Object {$_.Line}```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял, что нужно перенаправить вывод данных (в файл?) при нахождении заданных строк. Если так, то примерно вот:

```
# Массив поисковых строк
$searchterms = @('Строка1', 'Строка2', 'Строка3')

# Загрузим содержимое файла в память
$content = (Get-Content -Path "testfile.txt").Split("`n")

# Первый элемент массива поисковых строк
$j = 0

# Очищаем переменную $outFile, чтобы не записывать лишние данные
$outFile = $null

# Перебираем построчно файл и записываем данные в разные файлы в зависимости от найденной строки
$content | ForEach-Object {
    $currentSearchTerm = $searchterms[$j]

    if ($_ -eq $currentSearchTerm) {
        $outFile = New-Item -ItemType File -Path "$currentSearchTerm.txt"
        $j++
    }

    if ($outFile) {
        $_ | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Encoding utf8 -Append
    }
}
```

Содержимое `testfile.txt`:

```
awdwadwdadaw
awawdwadwa
Строка1
qweqwe
qwe
Строка2
asdasd
asd
Строка3
cxzcxz
cxz
Строка4
fghfgh
fgh
```

На выходе я получил 3 файла `Строка1.txt`, `Строка2.txt` и `Строка3.txt`. В первом файле только данные *после* `Строка1`, в третьем файле всё после `Строка3` до конца (`Строка4` для примера).